# TYPO3 6.2 - add parameters to typolinks with certain classes

Tags: hyperlink, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have to change the way TYPO3 outputs links. But only if I choose the style "internal-link-new-window" for a link in the RTE. In this case I would like to add certain parameters to the a tag. For example rel="..." data-i="..." and things like that.

Is that possible with typoscript? I did experiment a little but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at my solution for adding conditional wraps around RTE links.

[RTE - wrap link based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848152/rte-wrap-link-based-on-condition/21930670#21930670)

The last part of the TypoScript (where the wrap is added to the RTE link) is like shown below:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link {
  typolink.parameter.append < lib.parseFunc.tags.link.typolink.parameter.append
  wrap < lib.parseFunc.tags.link.newWrap
}
```

Here you can add additional `ATagParams` like shown below:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link {
  typolink.parameter.append < lib.parseFunc.tags.link.typolink.parameter.append
  typolink.ATagParams = rel="..."
  wrap < lib.parseFunc.tags.link.newWrap
}
```

So if you use the whole TypoScript from my solution and extend the typolink with `ATagParams`, then you are able to add additional parameters to links depending on certain classes.

Comment: thanks! :) ...in the meantime i ended up using a php user function. often a real programming language is so much easier and less cumbersome to use than the weird typoscript. :) i came across your solution before and it worked nicely for wraps but i also had to change the typolink.parameter and didn't get it to work like i want.